# Parameters in Ireport / Jasperreports

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I´m using a tool called `runjasper.jar` to fill a JRXML File.
In that file, I have a parameter called `querywhere`.
This string will be appended to the Connection SQL (MySQL DB) via `$P!{querywhere}`, but I got some problems by using some chars.
for example: `"`,  `'` and `(` and so on.

I´d opened the java file in NetBeans to debug it.
At that line:

```
JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parameters, conn);
```

Parameters is a string with the name
`querywhere`
that is equal to:

```
WHERE my_company_id ='12345'
```

(copied from NetBeans debugger)
That is OK.

If I print the Reportvariable

```
$P{querywhere}
```

in the report I will have a line like this:

```
WHERE m5_pdc.m5_company_id =\'12010901\'
```

If I set the parameter escaped by \ to

```
WHERE my_company_id =\'12345\'
```

the `$P{querywhere}` param is:

```
WHERE my_company_id =\\'12345\\'
```

So:
Short question, how can I transfer a string like:

```
WHERE my_company_id ='12345'
```

to the report.

Any idea how to transfer chars like `"` and `'`?
It seems that escape char `\` doesn't work in this case.

Thank you and best regards

Christian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the expression like this: ***`SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE strAttr=$P{strFilter}`*** in jrxml file.

The snippet from the report's template (jrxml file):

```xml
<parameter name="strFilter" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT city FROM address WHERE city=$P{strFilter}]]>
</queryString>
<field name="city" class="java.lang.String"/>
```

This code works fine for strings with single quotation, double quotation and parenthesis symbols:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
//params.put("strFilter", "Berl)in");
//params.put("strFilter", "Muni\"ch");
params.put("strFilter", "Stuttga'rt");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, pdfFileName);
```

Or you can use the expression like this: ***`SELECT .. FROM .. WHERE $P!{whereClause}`***.

The snippet from the report's template (jrxml file):

```xml
<parameter name="strFilter" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="whereClause" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[SELECT city FROM address WHERE city=$P{strFilter} $P!{whereClause}]]>
</queryString>
```

This code works fine for strings with single quotation, double quotation and parenthesis symbols:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
//params.put("strFilter", "Berl)in");
//params.put("whereClause", "AND city = 'Berl)in'");
//params.put("strFilter", "Muni\"ch");
//params.put("whereClause", "AND city = 'Muni\"ch'");
params.put("strFilter", "Stuttga'rt");
params.put("whereClause", "AND city = 'Stuttga''rt'");
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);

JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, pdfFileName);
```

Comment: It seems to be a problem by executing the jar file in php.
There is a function (escapeshellarg) that escape all Shell Chars.
Until now i don´t now how i can do a "unescapeshellcmd" because the function seems to be enabled permanently. thx @alex. Your solution seems to be the basicely solution and works as it should !

Comment: @ChristianNRW Welcome, Christian :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make the variable as string  while passing parameter in hasmap and create the parameter in ireport and declare it as string in properties.The string value what you set in hash map parameter same value it will replace.

Comment: Hi. I don´t really understand: JavaCode: Map parameters = new HashMap(); ..... a little bit below: String paramValueString = " WHERE bla = 'blub'";
Also a little bit below.
parameters.put(paramName, paramValueString);

in ireport the Param is declared as "java.lang.string"
so: where is the error ?